# Out of memory exception in class which is used in Reactive

Tags: c#, memory-management, system.reactive, idisposable

How can we release the resources in the class when the class is used in RX Framework ?
I have a class in C# 4.0 lib project, which contains web service proxies, ado.net objects etc and I implemented IDisposable also. This class has a run running method and inside this method, I am saving data into a dataset and finally when the method is finished, i save the dataset to DB.

In the Dispose method, I am setting dataset to null and other web service proxy objects to null. Yet it throws memory exception when this class is used frequently in the reactive extension methods.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
 {
     proxy object;
     DataSet object; // This dataset has 2 tables with relation set each other

     public string LongRunMethods(string code)
     {
        // iterrating a for loop...
        // insert new row into the 1st table of dataset in each loop
        // another loop
        // insert new row into the 2nd table of dataset in each loop
        // Bulk save the dataset to Database
        // return string;
      }

      private void Dispose()
      {
         // nulling all the objects...[proxies, datasets, etc

      }
  }
```

And this class is used by creating 1000 times as shown below.

```
   IObservable<string> RunProcess(Employee emp)
    {           
       using (MyClass p = new MyClass ())
        {
          return Observable.Start(() => p.LongRunMethods(emp.Code), scheduler.ThreadPool);
        }                        
    }
```

This EmployeeDatas is list of 1000 employee objects.

```
  EmployeeDatas.ToObservable().Select(x => RunProcess(x).Select(y => new { edata = x, retval = y }))
                .Merge(10)
                .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    SendReportStatus(x.retval.Item1, x.retval);                           
                });
```

Everything is working fine. But when it comes process the 300th or above employee object, sometimes out of memory exception is thrown in the MyClass.

I am using dispose method in MyClass which will release all the resource once it finishes. Yet why the out of memory exception.

what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure given that you haven't got much code there. From what I CAN see is that your Disposable clean up isn't called when you think it will be. Assuming that MyClass populates the DataTables in LongRunMethods, then you actually never clean up.

Your Dispose is called instantly after your MyClass is instantiated, and most likely before LongRunMethods starts!

Try replacing the above with...

```
IObservable<string> RunProcess(Employee emp)
{  
   return Observable.Using(() => new MyClass(), p => p.LongRunMethods(emp.Code), scheduler.ThreadPool);
}
```

This will dispose your MyClass AFTER you call OnCompleted().

Comment: Thanks. But Using needs some other parameters. Compiler error says Using dont have 3 overloads. How I can mention the threadpool here in Using ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is nothing in the Rx you have posted that would, in itself, exhibit a memory leak. As others have pointed out, you are disposing your class before the query finishes - and it's hard to say what problems that might cause without seeing more code.

However, you clearly have a leak. When confronted with this sort of problem, I suggest running a memory profiler on your code. This is the fastest way to get to the bottom of it.

If you don't have a high-enough version of Visual Studio, then you can download a trial edition of Visual Studio or any number of commercial offerings. I highly recommend [SciTech's profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) as it is extremely easy to use and has a pretty good tutorial.